# VSCode форматирование HTML кода

Tags: html, форматирование, visual-studio-code

Можно ли в VSCode настроить форматирование HTML кода так, чтоб не форматировалось по атрибутам тега по атрибутам, а перенос осуществлялся по параметру "html.format.wrapLineLength": 120
 Пример: 
Теперь:

```
<input
    type="email"
    onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
    id="inputEmail"
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Email address"
    required
    autofocus
/>
```

Надо:

```
<label for="inputEmail" className="sr-only">Email address</label>
<input type="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus />
<label for="inputPassword" className="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="password" onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} id="inputPassword" className="form-control" placeholder="Password" required />
```

Пробовал параметр: "html.format.unformatted": "input",
НЕ получилось.

Answer (score 4):

важный нюанс !!!:

- параметры пользователя
  глобальные
- параметры рабочей области
  локальные перекрывают глобальные
  хранятся в текущем проекте в файле `settings.json`

  ```
  .vscode
  ├── launch.json
  ├── settings.json
  └── tasks.json
  ```

при настройке переключение между файлами происходит по клику на надписи, подчёркнутые на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
{
    "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"
}

<input type="email"
       onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
       id="inputEmail"
       className="form-control"
       placeholder="Email address"
       required
       autofocus />
```

---

```
{
    "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-expand-multiline"
}

<input
 type="email"
 onChange={this.handleEmailChange}
 id="inputEmail"
 className="form-control"
 placeholder="Email address"
 required
 autofocus
/>
```

---

```
{
    "html.format.wrapAttributes": "auto"
}

<input type="email" onChange={this.handleEmailChange} id="inputEmail" className="form-control" placeholder="Email address"
 required autofocus />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]